# UI automation error using iOS 5.1 target

Tags: instruments

I use Instruments 4.3 with UI automation tool for sometime successfully.
Recently I upgraded my target iPhone4 to iOS 5.1 and UI automation is now giving following error :"An error occurred while trying to run the script" for the moment a script is started, no further info than that.

Even when Instruments is running independently from Xcode the problem is still their, also when "run on record" is ticked but no script is selected.

I even reinstalled Xcode 4.3.1 but without success.

Runs fine on simulator and previous iOS version though.

If anyone encountered this issue and has a solution, please reply.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you by any chance found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.